# Scaleing of different images uniformly

Tags: c++, algorithm, image-processing

I was working on age estimation project and stuck with the following problem:-

I have a database of different images of different people and for each individual there are pictures taken at different age. The problem I am facing is that for any person the pictures in the database has not been taken with the same distance hence the estimation algorithm on these set of picture is not working. I need to construct new database of pictures from the current database in which all the photographs are taken from the same camera distance. ***I am not able to find such a scaling method***. Zooming both in & out of the pictures is not able to solve this problem as the face becomes smaller or bigger which is not desired. Kindly help me !!!! to solve this problem

Comment: If the actual distance does matter (which I find surprising), then you cannot construct what you want from the existing images, because the information simply is not there.  You would need holographs for that.

Comment: I'm failing to understand you.  A picture of me at ten feet will have my face twice as tall and twice as wide as a picture of me at twenty.  Moreover, you haven't given us enough information to know if any given proposed solution would be useful to you.  What sorts of images are you using, what sort of software are you using on them, and exactly what would you like the algorithm to do?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to correct somehow the camera distance automatically that's a 3D transformation and not really a scaling issue only. Camera distance change implies change in perspective.

Answer (score 0):

The general problem you are facing is one of [Image Registration](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_registration) - there are many different algorithms and approaches depending on your specific problem complexity, resources, and quality requirements.

You can research toolkits such as OpenCV, VXL, and others to see if there is something appropriate for your needs.